# How to run multiple Unix commands in one time?

Tags: shell, unix

I'm still new to Unix. Is it possible to run multiple commands of Unix in one time? Such as write all those commands that I want to run in a file, then after I call that file, it will run all the commands inside that file? or is there any way(or better) which i do not know?

Thanks for giving all the comments and suggestions, I will appreciate it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077241/execute-combine-multiple-linux-commands-in-one-line

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Short answer is, yes. The concept is known as shell scripting, or bash scripts (a common shell). In order to create a simple bash script, create a text file with this at the top:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Then paste your commands inside of it, one to a line.

Save your file, usually with the .sh extension (but not required) and you can run it like:

```
sh foo.sh
```

Or you could change the permissions to make it executable:

```
chmod u+x foo.sh
```

Then run it like:

```
./foo.sh
```

Lots of resources available on this site and the web for more info, if needed.

Comment: hi, may i know why "history" is not working? I searched in the web and i saw we can execute command "history" in the shell script if use ". script_name", what if for my machine the permission is denied?

Answer (score 22):

```
echo 'hello' && echo 'world'
```

Just separate your commands with `&&`

Comment: Nice answer for the _title_ of the question, but missed the three references to "file" in the _body_ of the question. :)

Comment: No, that's the AND operator. You need a single `&` to run in the background. Also, this isn't the answer to the real question.

Comment: Keith, he meant the AND operator. It will execute them consecutively and that's what we want here. Else we would have thread safety issues.

Comment: @sarnold OP suggested using a file _might_ be a way, but the `&&` operator is also a great way to run multiple commands.

Comment: @EmileBergeron no worries, I'm not the one who downvoted this answer :)

Answer (score 7):

We can run multiple commands in shell by using ; as separator between multiple commands

For example,

```
ant clean;ant
```

If we use && as separator then next command will be running if last command is successful.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use a semicolon ';' and run multiple commands, like :
$ls ; who

Answer (score 2):

Yep, just put all your commands in one file and then

```
bash filename
```

This will run the commands in sequence. If you want them all to run in parallel (i.e. don't wait for commands to finish) then add an `&` to the end of each line in the file

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use multiple commands at command line, you can use pipes to perform the operations.

```
grep "Hello" <file-name> | wc -l
```

It will give number of times "Hello" exist in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. It's called a "shell script". In bash, put all the commands in a file with the suffix "sh". Then run this:

```
chmod +x myfile.sh
```

then type

```
. ./myFile
```

or

```
source ./myfile
```

or just

```
./myfile
```

Comment: Note that ending the file with a suffix of `"sh"` has absolutely no effect whatsoever.  The `chmod` only makes a difference if you include a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) and you execute the file -- the `./myfile` instead of `source myfile` or `. myfile`.

Answer (score 0):

To have the commands actually run at the same time you can use the job ability of zsh

`$ zsh -c "[command1] [command1 arguments] & ; [command2] [command2 arguments]"`

Or if you are running zsh as your current shell:

`$ ping google.com & ; ping 127.0.0.1`

The `;` is a token that lets you put another command on the same line that is run directly after the first command.

The `&` is a token placed after a command to run it in the background.