# Executing multiple commands without using ; and &?

Tags: linux, shell

I need to run a command `ls` and `cal` in single line

But i need to write it without using `&` and `;` symbols...

Is there any way to write it?

Comment: Why? This sounds like homework, or is it just a random puzzle you came up with? Obviously your ampersand and semicolon keys haven't been stolen since you could write them in the question text ...

Comment: What exactly is the context of the problem?  Why do you want to do this this way?

Comment: No i was playing a small web challenges.  And i got struck in  this point ... they blocked both symbols in it and there might be any way to solve it seems... just to know weather we have any alternatives to it...

Comment: Not particularly useful, but `! cal || ls` comes to mind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use backticks and echo

```
echo `ls` "`cal`"
```

The double quotes keep echo from destroying the whitespace in `cal`s output.

Comment: __passthru("grep -i $our_value contents.txt");__


we need pass our input in our value place and need to execute multiple commands

Comment: What is "passthru"?
And please ask the question you want answered, to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `|` will help you.  To read the listing of a directory with many files, page-by-page, I did `ls | more`

Comment: __preg_match('/[;|&]/',Sinput)__ 

Is there any other way without | symbol... Still it not works

Comment: @ViVek , Try looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077241/execute-combine-multiple-linux-commands-in-one-line)