# Merging Multiple Commands in a Single Command with Argument

Tags: batch-file, terminal, command

This question is a variation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077241/execute-combine-multiple-linux-commands-in-one-line#_=_).

In my case, the command has an argument. For example, suppose I processing sample.tex with texlive, to generate a dvi, ps and pdf respectively. The commands will be

```
latex sample.tex
bibtex sample.aux
latex samlpe.tex
dvips sample.dvi
ps2pdf sample.ps
```

Can I merge them together to a script file so that whenever I enter

```
makepdf sample.tex
```

all the above commands are executed sequentially, so that I get a pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is `makepdf.bat`:

```
@echo off
latex %1
bibtex %~N1.aux
latex %1
dvips %~N1.dvi
ps2pdf %~N1.ps
```

Execute it as you said before:

```
makepdf sample.tex
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working. When I use the set of commands, it the terminal says 'entering extended mode' and freezes there. But it works fine if I just replace the arguments with actual file names. Can you point me to some reference which explains the arguments?

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as aacini's code but it also supports long filename elements.

```
@echo off
latex  "%~1"
bibtex "%~n1.aux"
latex  "%~1"
dvips  "%~n1.dvi"
ps2pdf "%~n1.ps"
```

If any of the commands are batch files then add a `call` keyword before the command name.