# Executing multiple adb shell commands using Python

Tags: python, linux, shell, adb

I want to use ADB shell to access my device internal storage and then access information using Python. I know how to execute single adb command from Python using:

```
cmd1 = 'adb shell ls'
s1 = subprocess.check_output(cmd1.split())
```

Also I found out that we can use `&& or || or & or ;` to combine multiple commands when we are using linux terminal to execute the commands here at [link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334994/which-one-is-better-using-or-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-one-line) [link2](http://www.linuxnix.com/23-awesome-less-known-linuxunix-command-chaining-examples/) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077241/execute-combine-multiple-linux-commands-in-one-line).

But I cannot see(till now) how to use these and combine commands which one can use in Pyhton. For example I want to do something in Python which would give me the equivalent result of running these four commands in linux terminal.

```
adb devices
adb shell
cd /dev/block
find -name boot
```

So does anyone knows how I can execute this in Python.

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#

Comment: @miyamoto Thanks. But for my particular case, it can be solved using `cmd1 = adb shell find /dev/block -name boot` and then `s1 = subprocess.check_output(cmd1.split())`. So here I can get the answer in one command itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use communicate() method to do this

```
procId = subprocess.Popen('adb shell',stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
procId.communicate('cd /dev/block\nfind -name boot\n')
```