# Bash Nested Substring Removal (Extraction)?

Tags: string, bash, substring

I have something similar in a script I'm writing:

```
CMD="/path/to/cmd,there.sh"
TMP="${CMD##*/}"
echo "${TMP%%,*}"
```

Is there a way to nest the substring removals in line 2 & 3, or produce the same result in one-line, in pure bash, without going out to another program?  The length of ${CMD} is not static.  To be clear, I want the output to be simply "cmd".

I've tried the below, with various forms of brackets and quotations, but get a syntax error.  This is something (I think) was allowed but isn't in new versions of Bash.

```
echo "${${CMD##*/}%%,*}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, it's not possible to combine or nest string operations in bash.

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
[[ $CMD =~ .*/([^,]*) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Comment: Was wondering if you should make the regex `^.*/([^,]*).*$` for it to be more fault-proof? Or is just enough fine? I don't see a fail-case here, anyways.

Comment: @sjsam: That would probably be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Shell parameter substitution is primitive in that they don't provide functionalities like nesting. However, nobody prevents you from doing a `sed` thing here.

```
cmd="/path/to/cmd,there.sh" # Use lower-case identifiers for user variables
cmd=$(sed -E 's#^.*/([^,]+),.*$#\1#' <<<"$cmd")
```

The `<<<` enables the use of [herestrings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) in `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that zsh actually supports nested string operations, so I actually switched the interpreter to zsh for my script and the below works fine:

```
echo "${${CMD##*/}%%,*}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the script "in one line", just use `;` or `&&` to indicate the end of a line instead of a line-break:

```
CMD="/path/to/cmd,there.sh"; TMP="${CMD##*/}"; echo "${TMP%%,*}"
```

or

```
CMD="/path/to/cmd,there.sh" && TMP="${CMD##*/}" && echo "${TMP%%,*}"
```

A more elaborate answer about combining commands can be found below [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077241/execute-combine-multiple-linux-commands-in-one-line).

*Disclaimer:
I understand that it is debatable whether or not this is a one-liner. But if you are visiting this question looking for a way to throw this in bash, it may answer your question regardless.*