# How to run multiple Unix Commands in an Ant Target in one time

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ant

Could someone please help me with an example Target of how to run two (or more) Unix commands using a Bash shell from within an Ant Target but without writing a new shell script.

I found an answer here [How to run multiple Unix Commands in one time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673336/how-to-run-multiple-unix-commands-in-one-time) which is great but recommends creating a shell script which I don't want to do.

The code I am using so far is like this, it works but I am wondering if there is a neater way of doing it - in one tag perhaps with the two commands separated by a ";" or perhaps using an < exec > tag rather than the < shellscript > shown.

```
<target name="dos2unixTidyUp"  depends="deleteTemp" if="isUnix"  >
    <shellscript shell="bash" dir="${my-app-bin.dir}" osfamily="unix" >
        dos2unix *.sh
    </shellscript>
    <echo>dos2Unix formatting completed</echo>
    <shellscript shell="bash" dir="${my-app-bin.dir}" osfamily="unix" >
        chmod +x *.sh
    </shellscript>
    <echo>chmod +x *.sh commanded completed</echo>
</target>
```

For your answers please provide an Example
< target > 
answer in here !! 
< /target >

If its possible to separate commands using a ";" can the commands be on separate lines or do they have to be on the same line.

Comment: Just use <exec> task and separating two commands by ';' is the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers they did help me. I have managed to modify my Target like so. Having both unix commands on one line separated by the ";" also worked. If someone wants to post an example using an < exec > then please do so - that would also be helpful and I will mark that as a second Answer.

```
<target name="unixShellTidyup"  depends="deleteTemp" if="isUnix"  >
     <shellscript shell="bash" dir="${my-app-bin.dir}" osfamily="unix" >
          dos2unix *.sh ;
          chmod +x *.sh
      </shellscript>
      <echo>unixShellTidyup completed</echo>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
$ echo "hello"; echo "there"
```

will run all commands, or

```
$ mkdir "xxx" && cd "xxx" || echo "mkdir fail, will not cd ..."
```

will run 'cd' only if 'mkdir' success. if not, 'echo' will run